# Why would a new[] expression ever invoke a destructor?

Tags: c++, c++17, new-operator

From the C++17 standard (draft [here](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf)), [expr.new]:

> If the *new-expression* creates an object or an array of objects of class type, access and ambiguity control are done for the allocation function, the deallocation function, and the constructor. **If the *new-expression* creates an array of objects of class type, the destructor is potentially invoked.**

Why would `new[]` invoke a destructor? It's *new,* after all. It isn't *delete.*

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If construction of any object in the buffer throws an exception, the previously constructed objects must be destructed. That requires an available destructor.

Comment: For clarification: Does this mean that a new (non-array) could also potentially call the destructor? I believe so from what I am seeing but wanted to ensure myself it is true.

Comment: @DanielRobertMiller - An object not fully constructed won't have its destructor called. A non-array `new` doesn't require an available d'tor.

Answer (score 13):

You have not considered the word **"potentially"** in the quote you have mentioned from the standard.
It means that there is a possibility that invocation of the destructor *can happen*. And *it will happen* if construction of any object in the array throws an exception.

Combined with the following quote from [**`[class.dtor]/12.4`**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.dtor#12.4) which mentions **`[expr.new]`**, this becomes clear.

> In each case, the context of the invocation is the context of the construction of the object. A destructor is also invoked implicitly through use of a delete-expression for a constructed object allocated by a new-expression; the context of the invocation is the delete-expression. [ Note: ***An array of class type contains several subobjects for each of which the destructor is invoked.***  — end note ] A destructor can also be invoked explicitly. **A destructor is potentially invoked if it is invoked or as specified in `[expr.new]`**, `[class.base.init]`, and `[except.throw]`. A program is ill-formed if a destructor that is potentially invoked is deleted or not accessible from the context of the invocation.

Answer (score 8):

In action:

```
#include <iostream>

int counter;

class Destruct
{
public:
    Destruct()
    {
        if (counter++ > 5)
            throw counter;
    }

    ~Destruct()
    {
        std::cout << "Dtor called\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        new Destruct[10];
    }
    catch (...){}
}
```

You'll see output something like:

```
Dtor called
Dtor called
Dtor called
Dtor called
Dtor called
Dtor called
```